# SQL: Individually for each case reference number, count the number of "Success" tasks that are logged before a non-"Success" task

Tags: sql, count

I have a table which is a list of tasks performed for cases. This includes the case reference number, the type of task performed, and the datetime the task was performed. Something like this:

| Case Ref | Task Name | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Task 1 | 01/02/2023 00:00:00 |
| A | Success | 01/02/2023 00:01:00 |
| A | Success | 01/02/2023 00:02:00 |
| B | Task 2 | 01/02/2023 00:03:00 |
| B | Success | 01/02/2023 00:04:00 |
| A | Success | 01/02/2023 00:05:00 |
| A | Task 2 | 01/02/2023 00:06:00 |
| A | Task 1 | 01/02/2023 00:07:00 |
| A | Success | 01/02/2023 00:08:00 |

What I want is to create a new table, which will tell me case ref, task name, datetime, and then the number of successes which followed the task for that case ref only, until a different task was performed for that case ref. So for the above example, we would see this:

| Case Ref | Task Name | Datetime | Number of Successes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Task 1 | 01/02/2023 00:00:00 | 3 |
| B | Task 2 | 01/02/2023 00:03:00 | 1 |
| A | Task 2 | 01/02/2023 00:06:00 | 0 |
| A | Task 1 | 01/02/2023 00:07:00 | 1 |

This is the code I have currently:

"

```
with t1 as (
select distinct top 1000
[Case Ref]
, [Case Ref] [case ref 2]
, [GTH Task Name]
, [GTH Performed Datetime]
from Table
where [gth task name] in ('Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Success'))

, cte AS (
        SELECT [Case Ref]
                     ,[GTH Task Name]
                     ,[GTH Performed Datetime]
                    ,SUM(case when [GTH Task Name]='Success' and [case ref] = [case ref 2] then 1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY [GTH Performed Datetime] DESC) workings
              FROM t1
              )

SELECT [Case Ref],
        [GTH Task Name], 
       workings - COALESCE(LEAD(workings) OVER (ORDER BY [GTH Performed Datetime]), 0) 'count'
      ,[GTH Performed Datetime]
FROM cte
WHERE [gth task name] in ('Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3')
ORDER BY [GTH Performed Datetime]
```

"

This code isn't working properly. As far as I can tell, it's counting the number of successes after every task, but irrespective of which case ref they're connected to. E.g., I have a Case Ref A Task 1 followed by 10 Successes for Case Ref B, then another Task 1 for Case Ref A. It should return 0 successes for Case Ref A, but instead it returns 10. I would have thought that my " [case ref] = [case ref 2]" statement would fix this, but it does not appear to have done so. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using ?

Comment: I believe it's a network database, with a variety of many-to-one and many-to-many relationships, but in this case I'm just inner joining two tables - a table of Cases, and a table of tasks performed for cases - to create the "Table" in the SQL code. That part works perfectly fine, so I don't think it's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Looks like MS SQL Server, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a running count of non-SUCCESS records, you can pass it to an outer Group By to count.

```
Select [Case Ref]
  , min(Case When [Task Name]<>'SUCCESS' Then [Task Name] End) as Task
  , min(Datetime) as Date
  , count(*) - 1 as Number
From (
    Select [Case Ref], [Task Name], Datetime
      , sum(Case When [Task Name]<>'SUCCESS' Then 1 Else 0 End)
        Over (Partition  By [Case Ref] Order By Datetime Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as Grouping
    From A
)
Group By [Case Ref], Grouping
```

You can add whatever ordering makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Unfortunately when I try this I immediately get an syntax error message for line 8: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'To'."

By Line 8 I mean:
+ Over (Partition  By [Case Ref] Order By Datetime Rows Unbounded Preceding To Current Row) as Grouping +

Do you have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: OK, you did not give us a hint as to what data base you were using.  Now I'm guessing Microsoft Access, one of the few that don't support window functions.  Please add a tag with the actual data base you are trying to use.

Comment: OK sorry, it is `Rows Between Unbounded Preceding AND Current Row` not To Current Row.  I edited in the fix.

Comment: I think it's correct it's Microsoft Access I have, which was still causing syntax errors. I adapted your code into a succession of with statements, which works great for me. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think Chris' answer will work for people without Microsoft Access Databases, but as that's what I was working with, I adapted it into this version which works for me, by using a succession of with statements. Thanks again Chris!

```
with t1 as (
select distinct
[Case Ref]
,[GTH Task Name] [Task Name]
,[GTH Performed Datetime] [Datetime]
from Table
where [gth task name] in ('Task1','Task2','Task3','Success')
and [GTH Performed Datetime]>='01-01-2016')
, t2 as (
 Select [Case Ref], [Task Name], Datetime
      , sum(Case When [Task Name]<>'Success' Then 1 Else 0 End)
        Over (Partition  By [Case Ref] Order By Datetime Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as Grouping
    From T1), 
t3 as (
Select [Case Ref]
  , min(Case When [Task Name]<>'Success' Then [Task Name] End) as [Task Name]
  , min(Datetime) as [Task Performed Datetime]
  , count(*) - 1 as [Number of Successes]
From T2 
Group By [Case Ref], Grouping
)
select * from t3 where [task name] is not null
order by [Task Performed Datetime]
```